mat-checkbox checked property not respecting state
This is my .html:
<mat-checkbox [checked]="getState()" (change)="toggleState()">Example Checkbox</mat-checkbox>
<br><br>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="toggleState(false)">click</button>

and .ts:
  public selectedState: boolean = false;

  constructor(){
  }

  public toggleState(state: boolean) {
    console.log(state);
    if (state !== null || typeof state === 'undefined') {
      console.log('toggleState: false');
      return false;
    }
  }

  public getState(): boolean {
    console.log('selectedState: ' + this.selectedState);
    return this.selectedState;
  }

The mat-checkbox does not reflect the updated state, obtained through getState() function, despite the console.log() does print out the change/state.
Am I understanding the checked property wrongly? I presumed that the mat-checkbox state would update once the response from the function changes.
p.s.: I have read a lot of other answers and none applies. And I do not want to use Reactive Forms, despite it would easily solve this problem. And no, also do not want to use two way binding, since that would complicate my code.

What is the change detection strategy used in the component?

your toggleState method doesn't actually set the selectedState.

@BizzyBob toggleState always returns false in this test. When I check the checkbox and click on a button, it should uncheck it, but nothing happens.

@Balaji Default one, no changes aka. needing to force the change detection.

From the Material Checkbox Docs:

When user clicks on the mat-checkbox, the default behavior is toggle checked value and set indeterminate to false. This behavior can be customized by providing a new value of MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS to the checkbox.

Since you do not want to toggle the checked value, you can use the noop clickAction value, by adding the following provider to your component:
{
  provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, 
  useValue: { clickAction: 'noop' }
}

Also, you will want to trigger your toggleState() function whenever the checkbox is clicked, so change (change) to (click):
<mat-checkbox [checked]="getState()" (click)="toggleState()">
  Example Checkbox
</mat-checkbox>


Note: It's simpler to just bind the template to the property instead of calling a method:
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedState" (click)="toggleState()">
  Example Checkbox
</mat-checkbox>

Here's a working StackBlitz

This actually works! But I was so focused on this single checkbox that I forgot to mention the rest. In other places, I am using checkboxes as well, inside Reactive Forms. Of course those stopped working. Is it possible to have both? So with the update you provided, but at the same time keeping the previous functionality? Or do I now have to update all checkboxes I'm using?

Solved it. Instead of adding the MAT_CHECKBOX_DEFAULT_OPTIONS into app.module.ts, have added it into *.component.ts, where needed.
